# Postgres: How to update the column?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, dart, dart-pub

I use the [postgres](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/postgres) library to work with the database. I have a very large database. I need to change the character in the column. I do it like this:

```
  void replace(String col, String from, String to) async {
    String queryStr = "UPDATE $tab SET $col = replace($col, '$from', '$to');";
    await connection.query(queryStr);
  }
```

If the database has more than 1,000,000 rows, I get an error:

> Unhandled exception: TimeoutException after 0:00:30.000000: Future not
>   completed
>   0 _PostgreSQLConnection&Object&_PostgreSQLExecutionContextMixin._enqueue (package:postgres/src/connection.dart:402:24)
>   1 _PostgreSQLConnection&Object&_PostgreSQLExecutionContextMixin.query (package:postgres/src/connection.dart:318:12)
>   2 PG.replace (file:///home/vas/IdeaProjects/infovizion_platform/pg/bin/pg.dart:50:22)
>   3 main (file:///home/vas/IdeaProjects/infovizion_platform/pg/bin/main.dart:81:14)
>   4 _startIsolate. (dart:isolate/runtime/libisolate_patch.dart:287:32)
>   5 _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate/runtime/libisolate_patch.dart:171:12)

When I do the same requests manually there is no error.

How can I fix this?

Comment: You have to increase or set the timeout

Comment: @comrad how to set the execution limit in dart?

Comment: Let you method return a Future. Future.timeout(new Duration(seconds: 100000),...);

Answer (score 0):

You might try this version:

```
UPDATE $tab
    SET $col = replace($col, '$from', '$to')
    WHERE $col LIKE '%' || '$from' || '%';
```

That is, only update columns where the value actually appears, instead of all column.

Reducing the number of columns that actually change may speed the query.